# Remove Single item from map

Tags: android

I am able to display markers using google map v2. Now I want to remove a single marker but unable to do it. I tried using clear method but it removes all the markers.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
Marker _marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

for remove marker

```
_marker.remove();
```

---

Removes this marker from the map. After a marker has been removed, the behavior of all its methods is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try marker.remove(), it will do the job

Answer (score 0):

trythis

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

.....
.....
mapOverlays.remove(position);
```